# echo a command that echoes a quoted string

Tags: shell

So I'm trying to create a script1, this script has script2 data inside itself.
What I'm trying is:

```bash
echo "echo"Hello"">>script2
```

It should show:

(echo "Hello") inside script2 instead it is showing (echo Hello)

How do I achieve this?

Comment: After unquoting, your code becomes `echo echoHello` >>script2,  so you should find there `echoHello` and not `echo Hello`. Maybe you have a typo? Please always format your code properly, so that spaces can be recognized. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape the quote characters with `\`:

```
echo "echo\"Hello\"">>script2
```

Alternatively, use single quotes to ignore special characters inside the string:

```
echo 'echo"Hello"'>>script2
```

Comment: Hi,
what if I wanted something like
echo '{"a":"A"}'
as output